# Number of ways to select the election dates

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

A general election is to be scheduled on 5 days in May such that it is not scheduled on two consecutive days. In how many ways can the 5 days be chosen to hold the election?

**My approach**
There are 31 days in MAY month
$5$ days are election days and 26 days are non election days. Set aside
5 days 26 non election days will create 27 places to insert 5 election days, like: first gap  $\mathrm{d}_{1} \mathrm{d}_{2} \mathrm{d}_{3}$ $\mathrm{d}_4 \mathrm{d}_5 \mathrm{d}_6 \mathrm{d}_7 \mathrm{d}_8 \mathrm{d}_9 ........ 
\mathrm{d}_{26}$ last gap
Total 27 gaps to insert 5 days : number of ways $=27$ c 5

Am I going correctly

*any another approach*??? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: Two or two or more? I mean, is the selection 1,2,3 admissable?

Comment: @Alex, no , 1,2,3 are consecutive

Comment: Yeah  you are correct . Another way of doing is is such let the gap between 1st day of month and Ist day of election be $x_1$ , gap between 2nd day of election and 3rd day be $x_2$.....and so on till $x_5$(for 4th and fifth). Now for last day of month and 5th day of election be $x_6$. $x_1+x_2......x_6=26$ . And also $x_2,x_3....x_5>0$ .Replace these four by $w_i + 1$ hence $ x_1+w_1+w_2.....w_5+x_6=22$ where these 6 numbers are whole numbers , and this becomes a very general question called "beggar's method"

Comment: @aryanbansal sorry , it is not clear to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your answer seems to be correct!

U can also think like this,

There are 31 days in May.
Number of election days $=5$
Number of non election days $=31-5=26$ Let the days on which election is to be held is denoted by $E$
So 31 days will look like $X_{1} E X_{2} E X_{3} E X_{4} E X_{5} E . X_{6},$ where $X_{i}^{\prime} s$ are the number of days between the election days .They will satisfy the following constraints...
$$
\begin{array}{l}
X_{1}+X_{2}+X_{3}+X_{4}+X_{5}+X_{6}=26 \\
\text { where } X_{1} \geq 0, X_{2} \geq 1, X_{3} \geq 1, X_{4} \geq 1, X_{5} \geq 1, X_{6} \geq 0
\end{array}
$$
Now add 2 on both sides of the equation and substitute $t_{1}=1+X_{1}$, and $t_{6}=1+X_{6}$, we will get
$$
t_{1}+X_{2}+X_{3}+X_{4}+X_{5}+t_{6}=28
$$
$$
\text { where } t_{1} \geq 1, X_{2} \geq 1, X_{3} \geq 1, X_{4} \geq 1, X_{5} \geq 1, t_{6} \geq 1
$$
By using generating functions or otherwise the answer is $\left(\begin{array}{l}n-1 \\ r-1\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}27 \\ 5\end{array}\right)$